# JMeter Load Test on online purchasing

Tags: web, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I would like to talk some issues that I facing. Currently using JMeter to test the purchase train ticket on website. My question is how should I test the website. Example like, user will require to fill in quantity and information in order to purchase train ticket. After fill in, there is the "confirm" button to click and link to the payment gateway. I want to test, whether server able to hold 100 times on confirm button in 1second without slow down the performance. I would like to view the result of latency,ms of server when user press the confirm button. I have try to use HTTPS test recorder, but it seem like is a wrong way to test the server. Can anyone provide solution or guide me? Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is good for building test scenario "skeleton" - it basically speeds up the process of initial test plan draft creation. In other case you would have to use a sniffer tool to capture browser requests and manually create relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

1. The first thing you need to do is verify how does recorded (or developed) script works for a single user. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect responses. If everything is fine - you're good to go. If not (i.e. if there are errors or you hitting one page instead of performing transaction) - you'll need to look into the requests a little bit deeper and may have to do some correlation - the process of extracting some response bit with a JMeter [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), converting it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and adding as a parameter to the next request.
2. Once you're happy with how your scenario behaves **don't forget to disable View Results Tree listener**. Now it's time to define a load pattern. JMeter works as follows:

   - it kicks off threads (each thread represents a virtual user) within the time frame defined by **ramp-up** time.
   - each thread starts executing samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
   - if there are no more samplers to execute or **loops** to iterate - thread is being shut down.

   So make sure that you provide enough loops so your threads have enough job to do, otherwise you may run into a situation when half of threads have already finished their jobs and half of them haven't even started. [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) available via JMeter Plugins is extremely helpful
3. If your aim is to see whether your server is capable of serving 100 concurrent "Confirm" in a reasonable time frame and without errors - use [Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)
4. Use [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) to run your test. After test completion you can open JMeter GUI again, add i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener which will calculate and visualise metrics like response time, connect time, latency, etc.